# A Monoid application to subtypes doesn't compile with append operator, but works when explicitly called

Tags: scala, scalaz, monoids

I am making a Monoid for combining strategies for Retry Execution, and the RetryExecutor[T] is the based type.  I have defined the following base type and a monoid:

```
trait RetryExecutor[C] {
  def retry[T](f: C => T)(context: C): T

  def predicate: Option[Throwable]
  def application: Unit
  val retryEligible: PartialFunction[Throwable, Boolean]
}

object RetryExecutor {
  implicit def retryExecutorMonoid[A] = new Monoid[RetryExecutor[A]] {
  ...
}
```

and some base types like:

```
case class LinearDelayingRetryExecutor[C](delayInMillis: Long)(val retryEligible: PartialFunction[Throwable, Boolean]) extends RetryExecutor[C] {
  override def predicate: Option[Throwable] = None
  override def application = Thread.sleep(delayInMillis)
}

case class RetryWithCountExecutor[C](maximumRetries: Int)(val retryEligible: PartialFunction[Throwable, Boolean])(implicit val logger: Logger) extends RetryExecutor[C] {
  var remainingTries = maximumRetries + 1

  override def application: Unit = {
    remainingTries = remainingTries - 1
  }

  override def predicate: Option[Throwable] = {
    if (remainingTries > 0) None
      else Some(RetryingException("Retry count of " + maximumRetries + " exceeded for operation"))
  }
}
```

And I can combine them manually:

```
val valid: PartialFunction[Throwable, Boolean] = { case x: TestException => true }

val monoid = RetryExecutor.retryExecutorMonoid[Int]
val x = monoid.append(RetryWithCountExecutor[Int](3)(valid), LinearDelayingRetryExecutor(100)(valid))
```

but when I try to use the append operator:

```
val x = RetryWithCountExecutor[Int](3)(valid) |+| LinearDelayingRetryExecutor(100)(valid)
```

I get a compilation error:

```
[error] /Users/1000306652a/work/src/test/scala/com/foo/bar/RetryExecutorSpec.scala:25: value |+| is not a member of com.foo.bar.retry.RetryWithCountExecutor[Int]
[error]   val k: RetryExecutor[Int] = RetryWithCountExecutor[Int](3)(valid) |+| BackingOffRetryExecutor[Int](100)(valid)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the same issue in a much simpler case:

```
scala> import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> Option(1) |+| Option(2)
res0: Option[Int] = Some(3)

scala> Monoid[Option[Int]].append(Some(1), Some(2))
res1: Option[Int] = Some(3)

scala> Some(1) |+| Some(2)
<console>:14: error: value |+| is not a member of Some[Int]
              Some(1) |+| Some(2)
                      ^
```

The problem (which isn't really a problem, but more a design decision) is that `Monoid` isn't covariant—having a `Monoid[Option[Int]]` doesn't mean I have a `Monoid[Some[Int]]`.

The ideal solution is to provide constructors for subtypes that return values types as the supertype. Continuing our `Option` example, Scalaz provides these constructors as `some` and `none`:

```
scala> some(1) |+| some(2)
res3: Option[Int] = Some(3)

scala> some(1) |+| none
res4: Option[Int] = Some(1)
```

You could also explicitly upcast the values, of course, but if you *can* avoid ever using the subtypes as such your life will be a lot simpler.

Comment: The only problem is, `RetryExecutor[C]` is not a `Monoid`.

Comment: @MikeAllen: Right, since that's not the way type classes work—the whole point (exaggerating a little) is to decouple this kind of functionality from inheritance. `RetryExecutor[A]` has a `Monoid` instance, and Scalaz provides some implicit class magic that supports the `|+|` syntax here. (I wasn't the downvoter on your answer, by the way, although it's wrong in this context.)

Comment: But his code is a class that is not a monoid which is attempting to execute a `|+|` function it doesn't have. The `implicit def retryExecutorMonoid[A]` declaration doesn't define any arguments, so it can't perform an implicit conversion of an instance of this class to a monoid. There's no magic that can provide the `|+|` operation that I can see...

Comment: [Magic](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.2.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/syntax/SemigroupSyntax.scala#L7).

Comment: Ah, OK - I see it. Because `RetryWithCountExecutor` is a sub-type, and `Monoid` is not covariant. Sorry, you're right.

Comment: Yeah, I don't mean to sound combative, but this really is the way `Monoid` works in Scalaz.

Comment: Would it be sensible to define a companion object for these particular sub types that defined the apply() method to return RetryExecutor[A] rather than the sub-type as a good way to achieve this simply?

Comment: That would work, but it kind of goes against people's expectations about what `apply` on companion objects should do (namely, return something statically typed as the companion class). I'd say appropriately named methods on `RetryExecutor` would be better, but it's largely a matter of taste.